# Express union of constraints with inequality system

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, constraints

How can we express union of two or more constraints, for example $x\ge 0 \vee y\ge 0$, in an inequality system as below:

$f_1(x,y)\ge 0 \\f_2(x,y)\ge 0 \\f_3(x,y)\ge 0 \\ \qquad\vdots$

where $f_i\in \mathbb{C}^1$. This feasible set is not necessarily a convex set, hence there is not any linear inequality system for this problem. Is there any non-linear one?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking, you could write $\max_k f_f(x,y) \ge 0$, but that is just a notation, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes $\max$ function is an answer. However, it is another form of expressing $x\ge 0 \vee y\ge 0$. I am looking for functions $f_i(x,y)$ such that $f_i \in \mathbb{C}^1$ so I can use these constraints for example in solving an optimization problem with Lagrangian method.